# macbook-like multitouch trackpad on Linux Mint Cinnamon with touchegg

Tags: linux-mint, touchpad

I'm trying to get macbook-like multitouch trackpad gestures working on my linux machine. Currently working on Linux Mint 18, trying to get touchegg working, though I'm open to another multitouch system if it works properly. Machine is a Dell Latitude E7450.
I know the system is aware of multitouches at some level, but it doesn't seem to get processed properly in touchegg.

### trackpad type : ALPS

```
egrep -i 'synap|alps|etps|elan' /proc/bus/input/devices           
N: Name="AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint Stick"
N: Name="AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad"
```

### trackpad has capability to do multitouch

```
xinput list-props 13 
[snip]
Synaptics Capabilities (295):   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
[snip]
```

### some part of the system is aware of the touches I'm making

when I run

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event8 | grep "code 33"
```

I nicely see my single touches appear (first line when I touch it, second line when I let go):

```
Event: time 1487946648.539316, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1487946649.722918, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
```

for two-finger touches I get 2 lines on contact and 2 lines when I let go (I assume this is because my fingers don't make/break contact at exactly the same moment)

```
Event: time 1487946869.652686, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1
Event: time 1487946869.666681, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946873.257236, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0
Event: time 1487946873.257236, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
```

However, when I touch 3 or 4 fingers at the same time, I get output like this :

```
Event: time 1487946975.836029, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.836029, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.836029, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.836029, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.847879, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.847879, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.847879, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.847879, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.860206, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.860206, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.860206, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.860206, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.871836, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.871836, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.871836, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.871836, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.883832, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.883832, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.883832, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.883832, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.895856, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.895856, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.895856, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.895856, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.907803, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.907803, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.907803, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.907803, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.919821, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 1
Event: time 1487946975.919821, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.919821, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 333 (BTN_TOOL_DOUBLETAP), value 0
Event: time 1487946975.919821, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 334 (BTN_TOOL_TRIPLETAP), value 1
```

continuously, and extremely fast.

### touchegg command line

when I run touchegg on the command line, I get a list of available gestures, but nothing prints when I'm trying to do gestures.
If I first run (as suggested at https://askubuntu.com/questions/266057/cant-get-touchegg-to-work-with-my-touchpad )

```
synclient TapButton2=0
synclient TapButton3=0
synclient ClickFinger2=0
synclient ClickFinger3=0
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=0
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=0
```

and then I run touchegg again on the command line, I do get some output, but it doesn't seem to recognise the 3rd and 4th finger. I keep getting something like

```
[+] New gesture: 
    Type      ->  "DRAG" 
    Fingers   ->  2 
    Direction ->  "UP" 
    Action    ->  "SCROLL" 
    App Class ->  "Gvim" 
    Gesture Start 
    Gesture Update 0 "Drag" 
    Gesture Update 0 "Drag" 
    Gesture Update 0 "Drag"
```

in the output. Even for 3 and 4 finger touches it gives the 'Fingers   ->  2 ' part.

So what can I try next to get multitouch gestures working in the style used by macOS on a macbook?